# sorting entire xdocument based on subnodes

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have an xml of the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<contactGrp name="People">
  <contactGrp name="Developers">
    <customer name="Mike" ></customer>
    <customer name="Brad" ></customer>
    <customer name="Smith" ></customer>
  </contactGrp>
  <contactGrp name="QA">
    <customer name="John" ></customer>
    <customer name="abi" ></customer>
  </contactGrp>
</contactGrp>
```

I'd like to sort the list of customers based on their names, and return the document in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<contactGrp name="People">
  <contactGrp name="Developers">
    <customer name="Brad" ></customer>
    <customer name="Mike" ></customer>
    <customer name="Smith" ></customer>
  </contactGrp>
  <contactGrp name="QA">
    <customer name="abi" ></customer>
    <customer name="John" ></customer>
  </contactGrp>
</contactGrp>
```

I am using c# and currently xmldocument.

thank you

Comment: I'm confuse because `xpath` tag... If you want to select a node set then XPath could ve the right technology. If you want to properly sort a node set you will need the XPath engine host language. Bu if you want to transform an XML tree, the standar resource is XSLT.

Comment: I know, I can't seem to get it working for my problem.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy XSLT solution that works for any level of nesting of the `contactGrp` elements. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a stylesheet and use it to transform the document then:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/contactGrp">
    <contactGrp name="Developers">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="contactGrp"/>
    </contactGrp>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="contactGrp/contactGrp">
    <contactGrp>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:for-each select="customer">
        <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>

    </contactGrp>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you. I knew xslt was the correct way to go, but couldn't get the xml to sort the correct level. thank you

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(/* ... */);

foreach (var g in doc.Descendants("contactGrp"))
{
    var customers = g.Elements("customer").ToList();
    customers.Remove();
    g.Add(customers.OrderBy(c => c.Attribute("name").Value));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="contactGrp">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
     <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<contactGrp name="People">
    <contactGrp name="Developers">
        <customer name="Mike" ></customer>
        <customer name="Brad" ></customer>
        <customer name="Smith" ></customer>
    </contactGrp>
    <contactGrp name="QA">
        <customer name="John" ></customer>
        <customer name="abi" ></customer>
    </contactGrp>
</contactGrp>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<contactGrp name="People">
  <contactGrp name="Developers">
    <customer name="Brad" />
    <customer name="Mike" />
    <customer name="Smith" />
  </contactGrp>
  <contactGrp name="QA">
    <customer name="abi" />
    <customer name="John" />
  </contactGrp>
</contactGrp>
```

**Do note**: The correct results will always be produced -- regardless of the level of nesting of the `contactGrp` elements